# googlemock threads and InSequence

Tags: c++, multithreading, googletest, googlemock

Consider the scenario where there are multiple instances of a class, there are some worker threads to do stuff, each thread using a unique instance.

Consider the threaded code does something simple, such as:

```
thing->write("discover")
thing->read_until("\n", timeout)
thing->write("version")
thing->read_until("\n", timeout)
```

First off, I discovered that if I run a (non-threaded) test (which tests the above) the test will fail, for example:

```
EXPECT_CALL(thing, write("discover"));
EXPECT_CALL(thing, read_until("\n", timeout))
    .WillOnce(Return("hello");
EXPECT_CALL(thing, write("version"));
EXPECT_CALL(thing, read_until("\n", timeout));
    .WillOnce(Return("v99");
```

Unless at the start of the test, you add:

```
testing::InSequence dummy;
```

Without this, I discovered the mock uses the return value of the second call to "read_until" for each call to read_until made by the code under test, so I get

```
write: discover
read: v99
```

Fail.

Ok, so not a problem, just add the InSequence bit to each test.

However, if I have multiple threads that are started, the InSequence call makes it impossible to determine which calls will be made first, so it breaks the test (obviously). But without the InSequence bit, the test also fails because it always uses the last set expect value. Which is a little annoying. I know you can call .WillOnce(Return(val)) many times when setting the expectation, but is there any other way around this?

I'm asking because there a lots of calls (in the code under test) to this API in different orders - each expectation was nicely wrapped in a nice little helper function to reduce code duplication in tests, for example:

```
void discoverOk(thing)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(thing, write("discover"));
    EXPECT_CALL(thing, read_until("\n", timeout))
        .WillOnce(Return("hello");
}

void discoverError(thing)
{
    // simulate timeout, returns empty string:
    EXPECT_CALL(thing, write("discover"));
    EXPECT_CALL(thing, read_until("\n", timeout))
        .WillOnce(Return("");
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work so well with using .WillOnce(Return(...)) many times when setting the EXPECT_CALL.

Comment: I'd suggest you extract a [mcve] first. However, I also have a feeling that your code is tangled with multithreading, which makes it really tough to unit-test.

Comment: Can you try using ON_CALL instead of EXPECT_CALL. I guess in your use case you are not concerned about the order of execution

Comment: I did some more reading and discovered: EXPECT_CALL(....).Sequence(s) which I was able to utilize